# Configuring WCF Services in Code WCF 4.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

Hi, I am trying to configure wcf using code behind, below is the code:

```
public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)   
{



    string configPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wcfconfigDBPath"];

    // Enable “Add Service Reference” support 
    config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
    // set up support for http, https, net.tcp, net.pipe 
    if (isEnabled(configPath, "enablehttp"))
        config.EnableProtocol(new BasicHttpBinding());
    if (isEnabled(configPath, "enablenettcp"))
        config.EnableProtocol(new NetTcpBinding());
    if (isEnabled(configPath, "enablepipe"))
        config.EnableProtocol(new NetNamedPipeBinding());

}
private static bool isEnabled(string path, string elementName)
{
    try
    {
        string elementValue = string.Empty;
        bool returnVal = false;
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(path))
        {

            reader.ReadToFollowing(elementName);
            if (reader.Read())
                elementValue = reader.Value;

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(elementValue))
        {
            bool.TryParse(elementValue, out returnVal);
        }
        return returnVal;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code is not working. I am not sure when the "static void Configure" gets fired.

My question is, is there any way to enable/disable the protocol based on DB/xml configuration without bringing down the service?

Comment: This configure method will get invoked once before the service host is opened. This feature is to provide an easy way to configure a web hosted WCF service in code. That said you cannot add endpoints after your service host has started. But every time the service is activated this method will be called.

Answer (score -1):

New feature in .NET 4.5 which probably can be used in your case:

Note: The configure method is called by WCF before the service host is opened.

The Configure method takes a ServiceConfiguration instance that enables the developer to add endpoints and behaviors. This method is called by WCF before the service host is opened. When defined, any service configuration settings specified in an app.config or web.config file will be ignored.
The following code snippet illustrates how to define the Configure method and add a service endpoint, an endpoint behavior and service behaviors:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        ServiceEndpoint se = new ServiceEndpoint(new ContractDescription("IService1"), new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("basic"));
        se.Behaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior());
        config.AddServiceEndpoint(se);

        config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
    }

    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

Refer for complete example to:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277(v=vs.110).aspx